# Why do I have to `sudo`?

Tags: debian, terminal, sudo

I've followed a couple of tutorials on my RPi and a lot of commands start with `sudo`; what does it mean and what does it do?

Comment: Meta Question: http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/97/to-sudo-or-not-to-sudo

Comment: This is a great question, I can imagine a lot of beginners wanting information on this.

Comment: @berry120 yes but it would have been more suited to Unix/Linux SE because people run their Pi's on other OSes as well (I'm looking at you, RISC OS!)

Comment: Whaaaat? Year-Old Question! make that 2 years!

Comment: @evamvid This was one of the first example questions on RPi.SE...

Comment: @AlexChamberlain I didn't know that...Also I didn't notice that OP had tagged it Debian (in which case it's better suited). I guess there's a bit of an overlap...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`sudo` stands for Super User Do; it allows you to run as another user, usually the super user (`root`), to carry out administrative tasks, such as update the software, change filesystems, and start daemons.

`root` has the ultimate power and can run pretty much anything. It can, therefore, do a lot of damage to your system and in the worst case, you will have to start again.

**You must always understand what a command is doing before you run it.**

### Why do we have `sudo`?

For security reasons, normal users can't do everything. It prevents you doing anything too bad by accident and prevents malicious users damaging the system.

#### Why don't we sign in as `root` when we want elevated permissions?

`sudo` allows administrators to control what commands each user can run as `root`. For example, your administrator may allow you to run `apt-get` as `root`, but nothing else. Furthermore, all commands run via `sudo` are logged in `/var/log/auth.log`.

### Other Distributions

The default Debian image has `sudo` installed in advance, but others may not. You can often install it using the distributions package manager, or investigate other ways of gaining root permissions.

#### Arch

You can install `sudo` using `pacman`: run `pacman -S sudo` as `root`. You should then add a new user and disable the `root` account.

#### su

In Arch Linux (and other distributions that support it), you can use `su` (substitute user) command to assume the identity of any other user (including `root`). This means that all your future commands (in the current session) will have their permissions. However, you will require the their password and the commands you run won't, necessarily, be logged.

#### See also:

- [More extensive answer on Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3063/how-do-i-run-a-command-as-the-system-administrator-root)
- [`su` man page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Su)
- [How do I create a new user?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/487/how-do-i-create-a-new-user)

Comment: Do you think information on `su` might be useful to really complete the answer?

Comment: Propose an edit under the Other Distributions heading?

Comment: Further to this, I tend to write "sudo bash" as soon as I load my pi to avoid having to type sudo all the time. This lets you run everything with super user privileges. This is obviously a little dangerous, but with the rpi there is little majorly bad that you can do.

Comment: This is a very bad habit to get into!

Comment: @phalt Why don't you just log in as root then?

Comment: You can use `su` to switch to any user, not just root.  Eg, if you are logged in as root, you can su to a less privileged user temporarily to do something risky.  If you aren't root, however, you need the password of the user you want to su to.

Comment: @goldilocks Better?

Answer (score 2):

You usually use it to execute a particular command as root, rather than your current user. For security reasons the norm in the Linux world is for your main user to have limited privileges, and for you to switch to root whenever you need to do something you don't have privileges for (such as installing packages.)

Root is a bit like administrator in the Windows world - it's your ultimate "can-do-anything" user.