# How do I create a new user?

Tags: operating-systems, setup, security

Are there any security implications for creating (or not creating) a new user?

If need be, how do I create a new user or change the default user?

Comment: Completely up to you. There are no security issues in creating a new user. Personally I would immediately change it to my own name.

Comment: Is this Debian specific? Does Arch ship with a default user?

Comment: @AlexChamberlain: Arch only has root. You have to create additional users.

Comment: Either way, this really is specific to the software, not to the PI and should really be in the title.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Debian

The official Debian image ships with at least 2 users, `root` and `pi`. You will only be able to login to the `pi` account.

### How do I change `pi`'s password?

At the very least, you should change the password for the `pi` account, as anybody with a RPi will be able to log onto yours. To do this, run `passwd` from the command line and follow the prompts.

### How do I change `pi`'s username?

If, like me, you want to use your own name, you want to use `usermod` like this:

```
usermod -l newname -d newname -m oldname
```

There are more options for `usermod`, which can be found by running `man usermod`.

### Should I set a password for `root`?

Debian's `root` does not have a password and is inactive - you cannot login to it or `su` to `root`. You should not change this, as it is a security risk and `sudo` is more secure.

### So, are my files secure once I change the password?

Don't be too relaxed with your RPi's security though, the filesystem is not encrypted, by default, and therefore, anyone with physical access can just remove the SD card and read it using another machine.

### Related questions

- [Why do I have to `sudo`?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/282/why-do-i-have-to-sudo)

Comment: `usermod` replies `user pi is currently used by process 10190` when I run `usermod -l morgan -d morgan -m pi` (process 10190 is `bash`, the shell I am running). I cannot login as `root` because I don't know its password. Is it necessary to create a temporary user to change the `pi`'s username?

Comment: @Morgan Set the password for `root` by running `sudo passwd`.

Answer (score 18):

## Arch

A fresh Arch install ships with only the root user available. Thus you should definitely be creating a new user, as spending too much time as root is dangerous.
In addition, you should also change the root password, as leaving as default is a major security risk.

### Changing the root password

The password can be changed when logged in as root by running the `passwd` command.

```
# passwd
Changing password for root.
(current) UNIX password: 
Enter new UNIX password:
Retype new UNIX password:
```

### Adding a new user

A new user can be created with the `adduser` or `useradd` commands. `adduser` is probably easiest, the only required field is the name (you can skip the others by pressing enter):

```
# adduser
Login name for new user []:
```

You will be prompted for a new password for the account when it is created.

### sudo

If you prefer, you can use `sudo`, in a similar way to Debian users.

#### Installation

To install sudo, run

```
pacman -S sudo
```

as root.

#### Use

To allow a user to use `sudo` they need to be added to the sudoers file. This can be done in two ways.

- Add the user to the `wheel` group using `usermod` and uncomment this line in the sudoers file:

  ```
  %wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL
  ```
- or add the user directly to the sudoers file:

  ```
  username ALL=(ALL) ALL
  ```

> **NOTE** You should *never* edit the sudoers file with Vim, Emacs, etc. You
>   should *always* edit it via `visudo`. This prevents you from messing up the
>   syntax and rendering `sudo` unusable for you.

### Disable Root

If you want to you can effectively disable the root account by running this command as root:

```
# passwd --lock
```

This option disables a password by changing it to a value which matches no possible encrypted value.

This shouldn't really be necessary if you have a strong root password and have root access through SSH disabled.

Comment: Works with Raspian as well as Arch. Than you.

Answer (score 7):

## Extra trick on raspbian with `usermod`

`usermod` command won't run if there are any processes of the to-be-changed user running on the machine when the command is run.

**If your on console** of the pi there is a way to get around this without having to make another user (or set a pw on root):

Assuming nothing else is running with your username other then the shell on the console - no X session, no ssh login, etc:

```
exec sudo -s
cd /
usermod -l newname -d /home/newname -m oldname
```

### The reason this works:

- `sudo -s` tells `sudo` that instead of just running on command as another user that it should run new shell as the given user
- `exec` tells the shell that instead of spawning off a new process when it runs a command (hence leaving the shell process running as the login user) that the shell should *overwrite* itself with the new process - this means that when `exec` ed command ends the shell is gone - in the case of a login shell that equates to disconnecting from the login
- the `cd /` is optional. At minimum, things get a bit confusing if you move a dir your in (your login starts out sitting in the user `pi` home dir) but sometimes will cause a fail, better safe then sorry.

Therefor with `exec sudo -s` your overwriting your shell with a new shell that has been created as a different user.

P.S. be sure to give `usermod -d` a **full path** or you'll end up moving the account's home to somewhere you don't expect (and have a bogus directory entry in `passwd`)

Answer (score 6):

To add a new user in raspbian:

`sudo useradd -m -G pi,sudo,gpio,audio,video steve`

Then:

`sudo passwd steve`

Explaination:

`-m` - Create a new home directory

`-G group1,group2,group3` - Add the user to these groups, don't add `sudo` if you don't want the user to have sudo privileges.

`steve` - Name of new user

`passwd` - Linux requires a password to login, so set password.

Comment: very helpful to myself! cheers Epic person

Comment: The `-G` option doesn't seem to work anymore. Using `-group` only allows one group at a time.

Comment: The option `-group` changes the initial login group to the specified string. -G sets a list of groups that the user is in.

Answer (score 2):

I have been reading a bunch of how tos on this, but the easiest is also the simplest

Login as pi,

To add new user:

```
 sudo adduser john
```

After successful creation, add `john` to `sudoers` group

```
 sudo usermod john -g sudo
```

Logout:

```
logout
```

Login as `john`

Update package lists:

```
 sudo apt-get update
```

If it works, you're done...

Comment: What if he's using Arch?

Comment: After running "sudo adduser guest", "passed" and creating folder /home/guest I've got a working guest user. However, when I log in as that user the .bashrc file in /home/guest doesn't seem to get executed. I've created .bashrc manually and granted execute permission on it. Is there something missing still?

Comment: P.S. OK, I've solved it myself - .bashrc was sourced by .profile, and .profile did not exist for new user.

Comment: It should be called with the argument `-G`, because the argument sets the initial login group, it does not not add a group to the list.